# Cannot figure out how I should pass my data | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small app where I'm getting my data from an API via Redux. I'm successfully fetching the data as you can see here:[image]

and
[image]
and lastly 
[image]
So nothing wrong there. But now when I want to modify the data a bit and then pass the props to another component:

```
const event = this.props.events || [] // Getting data
const lock = this.props.locks || [] // Getting data
const customer = this.props.customers || [] // Getting data
const keyedCustomers = _.keyBy(customer, '_id') // Working
const keyedLocks = _.keyBy(lock, '_id') // Working

const events = event
  .map((event, i) =>
    <EventItem
      key={i}
      event={event} // Working
      customer={keyedCustomers[event.driver] || {}} // Nope!
      lock={keyedLocks[event.lock] || { address: {} }} // Nope!
    />
  )
```

And in my `EventItem` component:

```
export default class EventItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const { event, customer, lock } = this.props
```

The only thing that works here is `event`, nothing else.
So I wonder what am I missing here and if anyone can help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have typos.  `customers` and `locks` not `customer` and `lock`

Comment: The naming is very confusing. Adding "s" usually mean it's plural.. Here it's just for uniqueness reasons (I'm guessing), but it isn't even unique, because the same names are used (and "overwritten") further down. I guess it shouldn't be a problem because of scoping, but still...confusing.

Comment: @jmargolisvt What do you mean?

Comment: @jonahe What do you suggest I should do?

Comment: When you destructure props, the names have to match.  So `const { event, customer, lock } = this.props` assumes you have a `this.props.customer` and `this.props.lock`.  But you don't you have them as singular in your props.  You have them as plurals.

Comment: Not sure what @jmargolisvt is talking about. It looks to me like you're destructuring using names in singular, and that the EventItem component gets the props passed down using property names that are singular too. Maybe I'm missing something.

@MartinNordström. I think you should use variable names that reflect if they are a collection or not. So for example: `const events = this.props.events || []` (plural).  Then when you are mapping over the events data (the collection), you get an array of `EventItem` components back, so a good name could be `eventItems`.  Just a suggestion, of course.